# What are some inexpensive DIY options for fixing a low water pressure condition in a toilet?

Tags: water-pressure, plumbing-fixture, septic-tanks

### Low Water Pressure

We have a toilet that has very low-pressure flushing action. Is there anything that I can do other than calling in a professional? We've had a few people out to look at it and they cannot seem to diagnose this properly.

[image: Low-Pressure]

[Click here for flushing action](https://youtu.be/OxaZUdXPsn0)

### Background

The low-pressure is occurring on a guest house on the property. We can see a pipe that appears related to the toilet. When the toilet is over-used (flushed multiple times), we can see a bit of water overflow from the pipe. The toilet has never worked properly and the professionals we brought in could not assist other than suggesting a new external septic tank.

That option leaves me with a concern: Wouldn't they have to figure out the status of the current water outflow pipe and cap it before connecting to a new tank? That seems like a much bigger project so I am hoping to find a better solution from the community.

Please feel free to let me know if any of my assumptions are wrong or if I have missed other options. I am not a professional.

[image: pipe]

Comment: looks to me like you do Have a drain problem. Pull the cap on the clean out in the photo and if it overflows you have a plugged drain line to the tank. It is possible the tank is two small. (I have seen mother in law units that had a 55 gallon drum for a tank).

Comment: When was the last time you had the septic tank drained?

Comment: @BenWelborn - We bought the house four years ago and haven't had the tank (by the main house) drained. The only thing we can see by the guest house is this (clean out?) pipe. This is our first house requiring a septic tank, so my experience here is zero. I will do some research.

Comment: You should have the tank pumped every 3-5 years. Chances are the seller didn't pump it before he left (why would he?).

Comment: Honestly though, I don't really know what you mean by low water pressure,  and  low-pressure flushing action. These are both different things... neither has anything to do with a backed up septic... but seeing **water overflow from (what I presume is) a spetic cleanout pipe, would indicate a backed up (or full) septic tank**. However, flushing power is caused by _toilet tank_ (or bowl) issues (not the septic tank so much), and water pressure involves water supply to the house (has absolutely nothing to do with flushing).

Answer (score 1):

The immediate non-flush nature of your problem, as depicted in the video, indicates (to me, anyway) a **very** local obstruction, as in the toilet trap itself. You need to run a toilet auger (see pic) down through the toilet trap and/or pull the toilet to see if there is an obstruction immediately below. This could be anything from packed paper to packed solid material to a kid's toy to rocks from a fish tank. I have seen all those things and more.

If the sewer system itself were backed up such that there was water/waste all the way up to the toilet trap itself, your toilet bowl would overflow onto the floor when flushed and you would very likely have water coming out from under the toilet due to wax seal compromise.

[image][image]